# How might I build a templated functions that compiles differently if a template int is odd or even?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, c++20

```
class Whatever {
    public:
    // doThing overloads:
    template <typename T>
    inline static T doThing(T t, float n) {
        /*  It's a SmoothStartN function in my code,
            but don't worry about the specifics.
            Includes a for loop up to n times
            (result gets interpolated between non-integer ns). */
        return whatever;
    }
    template <unsigned int n, typename T>
    inline static T doThing(T t) {
        /*  Same as the other one, except now the compiler can
            unroll the for loop if appropriate.
            Or so I assume, anyway; I might be wrong. */
        return whatever;
    }

    // doMoreComplexThing overloads:
    template <unsigned int n, typename T>
    inline static T doMoreComplexThing(T t1, T t2) {
        float halfN = ((float)n) * 0.5f;
        return (doThing(t1, halfN) * doThing(t2, halfN));
    }
};
```

My problem: `doMoreComplexThing()` currently has to use the presumably-less-well-optimised version of `doThing()` in all cases. However, in half of all cases, where n is even, it can be evenly divided into integers and thus the more efficient template-uint version is viable.

How could I set this up so that, at compile time, `doMoreComplexThing()` detects whether n is even and uses the appropriate overload? Is such a thing possible? For that matter, is it likely any more performant to bother with this, or should I just stick with the float overload?

Comment: Sounds like a perfect use for `if constexpr`.

Comment: "*currently has to use the presumably-less-well-optimised version*" Unless you have actual evidence that your presumption is a fact, it's best to just ignore it and move on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer: Thanks to Quentin's suggestion, I believe a good solution looks something like this:

```
template <unsigned int n, typename T>
inline static T doMoreComplexThing(T t1, T t2) {
    if constexpr((n % 2u) == 0u) {
        unsigned int halfN = n / 2u;
        return (doThing<halfN>(t1) * doThing<halfN>(t2));
    }
    else {
        float halfN = ((float)n) * 0.5f;
        return (doThing(t1, halfN) * doThing(t2, halfN));
    }
}
```